# My python program fails to rewrite a node in AST

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to replace *`print`* with *`raise ValueError`*. But this program returns only `TypeError: expected some sort of expr, but got <ast.Raise object at 0x000001DF779469A0>`. How do I fix the following code to achieve my goal?

```
import ast


class MyVisitor(ast.NodeTransformer):

    def visit_Name(self, node: ast.Name):
        if node.id == 'print':
            result = ast.parse("raise ValueError").body[0]
            result.lineno = node.lineno
            result.col_offset = node.col_offset
            return result
        return node


program = """
f = 4 + 4
print("sth")
"""
tree = ast.parse(program)
my_visitor = MyVisitor()
tree = my_visitor.visit(tree)
code = compile(ast.fix_missing_locations(tree), "filename", "exec")
exec(code)
```

Comment: You are trying to replace a small part of an expression (just the reference to the name `print`, not even an actual call to the function) with a statement, which is something that exists on an entirely different level.  You need to go up a couple of levels to find the `Expr` node containing your `print()`, and replace *that* with the `raise`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visiting the `Expr` nodes instead, you can replace the print statement
with a `raise valueError` statement:

```
import ast

class MyVisitor(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Expr(self, node: ast.Expr):
        print(f"{node.__class__ =}")
        if node.__class__ != ast.Expr:
            return node
        if node.value.__class__ != ast.Call:
            return node
        if node.value.func.id == 'print':
            result = ast.parse("raise ValueError").body[0]
            result.lineno = node.lineno
            result.col_offset = node.col_offset
            return result
        return node

program = """
f = 4 + 4
print("sth")
"""
tree = ast.parse(program)
atv_out = ast.dump(tree)
my_visitor = MyVisitor()
tree = my_visitor.visit(tree)
code = compile(ast.fix_missing_locations(tree), "filename", "exec")
exec(code)
# raises ValueError
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python3.9+, you can actually use [refactor](https://github.com/isidentical/refactor) which has a much simpler interface than the `NodeTransformer`. For example the solution for your problem can be this;

```py
import ast
import refactor

class ReplacePrint(refactor.Rule):
    def match(self, node):
        assert isinstance(node, ast.Call)
        assert isinstance(node.func, ast.Name)
        assert node.func.id == 'print'
        
        value_error = ast.Raise(exc=ast.Name('ValueError', ast.Load()))
        return refactor.ReplacementAction(node, value_error)

program = """
f = 4 + 4
print("sth")
"""

session = refactor.Session(rules=[ReplacePrint])
print(session.run(program))
```